# How can I make the contents inside my UIView scrollable?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

I have a UIView that contains my UIScrollView (with a bunch of elements inside) in IB. The scrollView is wired up properly, but the content inside does not scroll. Not sure why?

```
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {

 scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,600);
 scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
 scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
 scrollView.scrollsToTop = NO;


 self.title = titleDescription;

 self.descriptionTextView.text = bodyDescription;
 self.addressTextView.text = address;
 self.phoneTextView.text = phone;
 self.websiteTextView.text = website;
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: You want the UIView to scroll or the UIScrollView to scroll?

Comment: What is the size of the scroll view frame?

Comment: The scroll view frame should be smaller than the content size (or the content size should be larger than the scroll view frame) for scrolling to be necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the scroll view's `contentSize` property in code (it can't be done in Interface Builder).

Answer (score 0):

Don't put an UIView inside the UIScrollView.

Make the scroll view as tall as you like, and the iPhone will take care of your "scrolling needs".

You can, however, put multiple UIViews inside the UIScrollView and you'll be able to scroll the views to get where you want to, but I don't think that's what you're aiming for...

Comment: i have a lot of text fields. i just want the view to be scrollable vertically so all of them can be accessed

Comment: even if i put the contents in the UISrollView and the UIScrollView in my UIView, no scrolling...